# Android Class Cast Exception when extending DialogPreference

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I have extended the DialogPreference class and hoping i could make a solution work like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425702/layout-for-timepicker-based-dialogpreference).

I would like to implement my TimePreference class in my system but when calling the PreferenceActivity i get a run time exception

```
04-15 16:47:31.555: W/MediaPlayer(28689): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
04-15 16:47:31.555: W/MediaPlayer(28689): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
04-15 16:47:31.594: D/libEGL(28689): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
04-15 16:47:31.609: D/libEGL(28689): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-15 16:47:31.633: D/libEGL(28689): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-15 16:47:31.637: D/libEGL(28689): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-15 16:47:31.793: D/OpenGLRenderer(28689): Enabling debug mode 0
04-15 16:47:36.938: D/AndroidRuntime(28689): Shutting down VM
04-15 16:47:36.938: W/dalvikvm(28689): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a4c1f8)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.timer/app.timer.PrefsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:205)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.preference.Preference.getPersistedString(Preference.java:1396)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at app.timer.TimePreference.onSetInitialValue(TimePreference.java:110)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.preference.Preference.dispatchSetInitialValue(Preference.java:1312)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.preference.Preference.onAttachedToHierarchy(Preference.java:1124)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addPreference(PreferenceGroup.java:156)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:97)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:38)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:488)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:269)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1403)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at app.timer.PrefsActivity.onCreate(PrefsActivity.java:12)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-15 16:47:37.024: E/AndroidRuntime(28689):    ... 11 more
04-15 16:47:37.137: D/dalvikvm(28689): GC_CONCURRENT freed 230K, 4% free 9362K/9671K, paused 2ms+13ms
```

My pref.xml looks like this and works if i remove  my TimePreference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <PreferenceCategory 
        android:key="time_settings"
        android:title="@string/time_settings"
        android:summary="@string/time_settings_summary">
        <app.timer.TimePreference
            android:key="synchronize"
            android:title="@string/synchronize" 
            android:summary="@string/synchronize_summary" 
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dialog_time" />  
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:key="sound_cat"
        android:title="@string/sound_cat"
        android:summary="@string/sound_cat_summary">
        <CheckBoxPreference 
            android:key="mute"
            android:title="@string/mute"
            android:summary="@string/mute_summary"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_audio_vol" />
        <ListPreference 
                android:key="beep_interval"
                android:title="@string/beep_interval"
                android:summary="@string/beep_interval_summary"
                android:entries="@array/beep_interval_options"
                android:entryValues="@array/beep_interval_option_values"
                android:defaultValue="2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_audio_alarm" />      
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:key="screen"
        android:title="@string/screen_cat"
        android:summary="@string/screen_cat_summary">
        <CheckBoxPreference 
            android:key="screen_dim"
            android:title="@string/screen_dim"
            android:summary="@string/screen_dim_summary"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_view" />
        <ListPreference 
                android:key="format"
                android:title="@string/format"
                android:summary="@string/format_summary"
                android:entries="@array/format_options"
                android:entryValues="@array/format_option_values"
                android:defaultValue="0"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
        <CheckBoxPreference 
            android:key="indigo"
            android:title="@string/indigo"
            android:summary="@string/indigo_summary"
            android:icon="@drawable/brightness" />
   </PreferenceCategory>
   <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/about" 
        android:summary="@string/about_summary" >          
   <ListPreference
       android:key="version_build"
       android:enabled="false"
       android:title="version 1.01"
       android:summary="build 3"  /> 
   </PreferenceCategory>  
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And this i the TimePreference class

```
package app.timer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class TimePreference extends DialogPreference {
    protected int lastHour=0;
    protected int lastMinute=0;
    protected boolean is24HourFormat;
    protected TimePicker picker=null;
    protected TextView timeDisplay;

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt) {
        this(ctxt, null);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(ctxt, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(ctxt, attrs, defStyle);

        is24HourFormat = DateFormat.is24HourFormat(ctxt);
        setPositiveButtonText("Set");
        setNegativeButtonText("Cancel");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if(is24HourFormat) {
            return ((lastHour < 10) ? "0" : "")
                    + Integer.toString(lastHour)
                    + ":" + ((lastMinute < 10) ? "0" : "")
                    + Integer.toString(lastMinute);
        } else {
            int myHour = lastHour % 12;
            return ((myHour == 0) ? "12" : ((myHour < 10) ? "0" : "") + Integer.toString(myHour))
                    + ":" + ((lastMinute < 10) ? "0" : "") 
                    + Integer.toString(lastMinute) 
                    + ((lastHour >= 12) ? " PM" : " AM");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        picker=new TimePicker(getContext().getApplicationContext());
        return(picker);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);
        picker.setIs24HourView(is24HourFormat);
        picker.setCurrentHour(lastHour);
        picker.setCurrentMinute(lastMinute);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindView(View view) {
        View widgetLayout;
        int childCounter = 0;
        do {
            widgetLayout = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(childCounter);
            childCounter++;
        } while (widgetLayout.getId() != android.R.id.widget_frame); 
        ((ViewGroup) widgetLayout).removeAllViews();
        timeDisplay = new TextView(widgetLayout.getContext());
        timeDisplay.setText(toString());
        ((ViewGroup) widgetLayout).addView(timeDisplay);
        super.onBindView(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (positiveResult) {
            picker.clearFocus();
            lastHour=picker.getCurrentHour();
            lastMinute=picker.getCurrentMinute();

            String time=String.valueOf(lastHour)+":"+String.valueOf(lastMinute);

            if (callChangeListener(time)) {
                persistString(time);
                timeDisplay.setText(toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return(a.getString(index));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
        String time=null;

        if (restoreValue) {
            if (defaultValue==null) {
                time=getPersistedString("00:00");
            }
            else {
                time=getPersistedString(defaultValue.toString());
            }
        }
        else {
            if (defaultValue==null) {
                time="00:00";
            }
            else {
                time=defaultValue.toString();
            }
            if (shouldPersist()) {
                persistString(time);
            }
        }

        String[] timeParts=time.split(":");
        lastHour=Integer.parseInt(timeParts[0]);
        lastMinute=Integer.parseInt(timeParts[1]);;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String

the above line indiacates that some where in your code you are trying to convert a boolean variable to string. Just check it once